# Can someone explain to me how log2foldchange data are grouped together in DESeq2?

Tags: generics, grouping, bioinformatics

In the below plot I am comparing two sites: Alfisol and Ultisol. For further downstream analysis, I want to know which genera are differentially abundant between those two sites.

I see that Penicillium is downregulated to -20 log2FoldChange from zero.
So that essentially means that one of those two sites has 20x fewer Penicillium counts than the other, and if Penicillium had been positive, some sites' Penicillium counts would be 20x as large as the other.

So I need some explanation on how DESeq2 groups or assigns which site contains the upregulated or downregulated taxa. Is it the Ultisol that contains the downregulated Penicillium or is the Alfisol?

[image: Dot plot of log2 fold change vs. microbial genera]

I've looked back through the meta data and found the normalized counts to verify which site is which. But I've seen so many of these graphs on differential abundance publications and they never explicitly show which *group* is upregulated or downregulated. It's just GroupX vs. GroupY or "healthy" vs. "nothealthy".

So I have to be missing something in my interpretation of these graphs.

[image: Table of differential abundance]

This table is a subset of the data for the above image.

Code Below:

```
siteds <- phyloseq_to_deseq2(Soil, ~ Site)

gm_mean = function(x, na.rm=TRUE){ exp(sum(log(x[x > 0]), 
na.rm=na.rm) / length(x))}

geoMeans = apply(counts(siteds), 1, gm_mean)
siteds = estimateSizeFactors(siteds, type="ratio", geoMeans = 
geoMeans) #alt types are "poscounts" and "iterate"
siteds = estimateDispersions(siteds, fitType = "local")

#fitting
siteds = DESeq(siteds, test="Wald", fitType="parametric")

#residuals and table
res = results(siteds)
res = res[order(res$padj, na.last=NA), ]
alpha = 0.05
sigtab1 = res[(res$padj < alpha), ]
sigtab1 = cbind(as(sigtab1, "data.frame"), as(tax_table(Soil) 
[rownames(sigtab1), ], "matrix"))
head(sigtab1)

#ggplot
ggplot(sigtab1, aes(y=genus, x=log2FoldChange, color=phylum)) + 
  labs(y = "Genus", x = "Site (log2FoldChange)") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.0, color = "gray", size = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  labs(color = "Phylum")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0, 
vjust=0.5),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face = "italic"),
    legend.text = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

Comment: There are several ways to define the contrasts for DESeq2, so without seeing your code it's impossible to say which way the change goes. In general, when comparisons are expressed as A vs. B, it means A is your condition of interest and B is control, so positive log(fold change) means A is larger than B, and negative means the opposite.

Comment: I understand that aspect, but how do I know which site is being defined as A and Which site is being defined as B? I'll add my code for reference.

Comment: Nevermind I got it.  DESeq loads them in alphabetical order of the samples listed. So Alfisol would be assigned A and Ultisol would be assigned B.  If I have more than 2 treatments I can specify which treatment should be used as the control.